# Modify html via php

Tags: php, jquery, dom, phpquery

Hello I'm doing this to add a string after a div in an html page with jquery:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PrependItemsToList();">Prepend items</a>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function PrependItemsToList()
{       
    $("#content_gallery").prepend($("<li></li>").text("prepend() item"));

}
</script>
```

Now I need to do it server side, any idea on how to implement it in php? I found phpquery but didn't find good docs about it.

Comment: This needs a bit more info. On server side you can just, you know, put the text there when you generate the page, or are you fetching the page from somewhere else?

Comment: The page is already existing, let's say I have a page one.html and I want to "prepend" on it a string from a php script.

Comment: Do you mean prepend on click or before the page loads?

Comment: I mean prepend on click.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying you want to do an AJAX call that returns HTML to be prepended to your `content_gallery` div?

```
<a class="prependLink" href="#">Prepend items</a>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function PrependItemsToList()
{       
    var url="yourpage.php";
    $.ajax(url, {
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#content_gallery").prepend(data);
      });
    });
}

$('.prependLink').click(function(e){
  PrependItemsToList();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Of course, this approach is pointless if you aren't loading any information that isn't context-sensitive (ie. you pass some parameters to your remote page through your ajax call).

Posting more information will help us better answer your question.

Comment: What I want to do is to add a line of code after content_allery div when i click on a link, and I want to save this change on the page on server. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: You want to modify the DOM of of an HTML page using JavaScript, and then save it to your server... using JavaScript?

Comment: No, I want to modify the DOM of an HTML page using PHP to write changes on the server, can you help me?
The JS code I posted is just to explain what I'd like to do in PHP. Thank you

Comment: You would need to pass information to your php file via the ajax call (stuff it in the `data` property of the $.ajax options object).  Then your php file would have to run a database query that inserts a record into your database, assuming that's what you have in mind.   For that you'll need MySQL (or equivalent).  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for some good starter code.